# What is the fewest number of divs that could be used to create the following page layout?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, html4

**update**

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dougrchamberlain/nMkxE/

See how it all falls apart. the width of the id=middle should span the entire remaining center `#left:width - #wrapper:width = #middle:width`

if #right contains any content then

`(#left:width + #right:width) - #wrapper:width = #middle:width`

**latest edit**

Just for everyon's information.  The image below was created in MSpaint.  No HTML used at all.

**edit**

This is not supposed to be a trick question.  plus please only consider html4 as an option. apparently I missed the HTML4 tag.  Also, are you all considering the fact that the right pane should be collapsed when empty.

[image: Div layout structure]

Not including any nested divs for the actual features, ie menus content areas etc...

My count is 6???

Comment: I think you're right: header, content wrapper, left, center, right, and footer.

Comment: Zero, use a table! :P
http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

Comment: It's probably not what you're looking for, but nobody *really* cares if it takes 5 or 10 or any number in between :) What kind of answer are you looking for here?

Comment: @aaronhathaway   Remind me to hurt you later...

Comment: your question asks for a count, but you seem to want code. hmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to wrap your elements in a fixed width div, you only need 5 - otherwise 6.

1. header
2. left
3. middle
4. right
5. footer
6. *wrapper (optional)*

I just hope you're not trying to save a few bytes by minimizing the amount of divs for the layout :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You can get away with just 4 divs if you use header, left, center, and right, and simply set the first element in the footer to clear: left;

The easiest way to do that is to do something like

body p { clear: left; }

as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/86M3M/1/

...and If you use html5: No divs needed ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>    
    <head>...</head>
    <body>

    <header>
       ...
       <nav id="main"> ... </nav>
    </header>

    <nav id="left"> ... </nav>

    <section id="main_content"> ... </section>

    <section id="right_content"> ... </section>

    <footer> ... </footer>

    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: For html less than 5 however, I'm pretty sure 5 divs is the minimum for that layout. Even if you need the entire page to have a fixed width, you can set that on the body so there's no need for a 6th div.

Comment: isn't there a bug with IE6 and setting body width?

Comment: I tried your jsfiddle code.  The results rendered in my browswer did not match the picture in OP.

Comment: #main_content should be a <div> and #right_content should be an <aside>. The HTML5 parser will consider everything that is not in a <header>, <footer>, <nav>, <section> and <aside> the main content. <section> can be used, for example, two times in a <nav> to separate your navigation menu in two.

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain: That very well may be; I have the luxury of being able to ignore IE6, so that didn't occur to me.